# Is there any wrong with my code that does not allow to keep cookies on mobile browser after they close the app?

Tags: javascript

I create a cookie to last for a week that it works as it should on desktop browser but not in iPhone browsers.

When I close the application in iPhone, let's say Safari browser, the cookie is gone, even it is set to be on 7 days and not a session.

How to keep the cookie at the device even after this?
What is a suggested alternative methods ?

```
function createCookie(name, value, days) {

    var c_date,
    c_name = name + "=" + value + ";",
    c_expi = "",
    c_path = "path=/";

    if (days > 0) {
        c_date = new Date();
        c_date.setTime(c_date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        c_expi = "expires=" + c_date.toGMTString() + ";";
    }

    // create the cookie
    document.cookie = c_name + c_expi + c_path;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your settings in Safari are right? Cookies should normally stay saved, even on Safari for iOS.
Maybe try this: http://support.apple.com/kb/TS4207

Comment: I think your answer is irrelevant since I will not educate users how to keep cookies on their browser after they close the browser, but I care on what I am doing wrong in coding that will not allow me to keep the cookie in their browser. I have updated my question with code.

Comment: The questions is if YOU are allowing cookies to be stored, because my cookies are always working using the Safari for iOS Browser.

Comment: cookies are stored until you remove the application from the application list.